How do I get the footnote number in Word document?
In office-js when I create a footnote, it returns a Word.NoteItem object, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to get the index of the footnote.
const footnote = range.insertFootnote();

// How do I know if it's footnote #5 or #4 or some other number?


Essentially when I insert a footnote in a document I want to get the number (superscript) that's added to the document so I know which footnote it is.
Image of  what I'm looking to get
What I've tried
The only thing that seems to work is to load all the footnotes in the document and loop through all of them, but that is really bad performance wise.
Ex:
const footnotes = context.document.body.footnotes.load("items");
context.sync(); 

footnotes.items.forEach(x => ...);

Having to do this every time a footnote is inserted isn't great for performance as we expect hundreds of footnotes in our application.

The note numbers are volatile. If a note is deleted or a new one inserted, the numbers of all following notes change. Similarly, if text containing a note is moved. Is this going to be a problem for you scenario? In other words, do you need each note to get a fixed ID number?

@RickKirkham A fixed ID would honestly be the best option if possible

But even if I could get the index it would still be helpful.

Your scenario isn't clear. Please explain why you need the note numbers. If we pretend that they are now volatile, what would your code do and what would it look like?

@RickKirkham Inside footnotes we have content controls. Each time our application creates a footnote we add a content control inside of it with some data. The problem is that we don't know which footnote number it is at the point of creation.
This means, anytime we add a footnote we have to do the expensive operation of loading all the footnotes and their content controls to get the index which is expensive. We also have to do this when removing a footnote. It would be nice if this information was readily available on creation or deletion so we could implement a cache for performance.

To associate a unique ID to each footnote, try this:
Have global variables for an array and a counter:
const myFootnotes = [];
let latestFixedFootnoteID = 1;

Whenever the code creates a new footnote, it pairs this object with a fixed ID in a parent object and then pushes that parent object onto the array, while incrementing the counter.
const footnote = range.insertFootnote();
myFootnotes.push( { latestFixedFootnoteID++, footnote });

Alternatively, use the JavaScript Map object (not the map() function). One advantage of using Map is that the keys don't have to be strings, so you could use the latestFixedFootnoteID as the key name when you create a new footnote.
let latestFixedFootnoteID = 1;
const myFootnotes = new Map();

    ...

const footnote = range.insertFootnote();
myFootnotes.set(latestFixedFootnoteID++, footnote);


If you want to impress your friends, initialize the counter to 0, and then pre-increment the counter by putting the "++" at the start of the variable name: ++latestFixedFootnoteID.

But what if they add a footnote in-between others? For example if I have footnote 1 and 2 then I put one in-between 1 and 2.
Footnote 2 will now become footnote 3. How do I account for that scenario?

See my new comment on your original post.
